# How to store different part of URL text content to different String arrays in android

Tags: android

We have a text file which we are placing in our server which have our required data needed in our app.

http://www.example.com/data.txt

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/data.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Inside text file data is structure like below.Each part of text file should go to different Arrays.

```
titles
item1
item2
item3        //item titles should go to item[] array
Descriptions
Description1
Description2
Description3 //Descriptions should go to description[] array
Prices
Price1
Price2
Price3       //Prices should go to price[] array
```

Or is there a better way to use xml instead of text, If yes how it can be done for same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some library link asynk http. Yhis lib but also other, provide a simple callback for different type of response. For example JsonResponHandler or TextResponseHandler.